# rbenv install 2.3.1 gives "BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.5) and configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: ruby

I feel ashamed to ask a question here since I just want to start learning programming and now already spend a day to try all solutions offered. So far nothing helped.

```
(base) [ruby-build (master)]$ rbenv install 2.6.3
ruby-build: use openssl from homebrew
Downloading ruby-2.6.3.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.3.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.6.3...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.5 using ruby-build 20190423-4-gac92ec0)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/19/1hf7txt144z0k3flz7fy50y40000gn/T/ruby-build.20190609115817.37848
Results logged to /var/folders/19/1hf7txt144z0k3flz7fy50y40000gn/T/ruby-build.20190609115817.37848.log

Last 10 log lines:
tool/config.guess already exists
tool/config.sub already exists
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/19/1hf7txt144z0k3flz7fy50y40000gn/T/ruby-build.20190609115817.37848/ruby-2.6.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I am really a beginner.

This is the config.log that is mentioned:

This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

$ ./configure --prefix=/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl

### ---------

### Platform.

### ---------

hostname = MacBook-Pro-van-J.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 18.6.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0: Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0: Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 402 tasks, 1379 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 1.90, Mach factor: 2.09
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users//anaconda3/bin
PATH: /Users//anaconda3/condabin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin

### -----------

### Core tests.

### -----------

configure:2996: checking for ruby
configure:3014: found /usr/bin/ruby
configure:3027: result: /usr/bin/ruby
configure:3105: checking build system type
configure:3119: result: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
configure:3207: checking host system type
configure:3220: result: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
configure:3240: checking target system type
configure:3253: result: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
configure:3905: checking for C compiler version
configure:3914: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang --version >&5
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users//anaconda3/bin
configure:3925: $? = 0
configure:3914: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -v >&5
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users//anaconda3/bin
configure:3925: $? = 0
configure:3914: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -V >&5
clang-4.0: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang-4.0: error: no input files
configure:3925: $? = 1
configure:3914: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -qversion >&5
clang-4.0: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
clang-4.0: error: no input files
configure:3925: $? = 1
configure:3945: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3967: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe  -I/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -L/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs conftest.c  >&5
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:3971: $? = 1
configure:4009: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4014: error: in `/var/folders/19/1hf7txt144z0k3flz7fy50y40000gn/T/ruby-build.20190610140025.11270/ruby-2.6.3':
configure:4016: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See`config.log' for more details

### ----------------

### Cache variables.

### ----------------

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe '
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='-I/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value='-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++14 -fmessage-length=0'
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-L/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_cflags_set=
ac_cv_env_cflags_value=
ac_cv_env_cppflags_set=
ac_cv_env_cppflags_value=
ac_cv_env_cxxflags_set=
ac_cv_env_cxxflags_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
ac_cv_path_BASERUBY=/usr/bin/ruby
ac_cv_prog_CC=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
ac_cv_target=x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0

### -----------------

### Output variables.

### -----------------

ALLOCA=''
AR='/Users//anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar'
ARCHFILE=''
ARCH_FLAG=''
ARFLAGS=''
AS='/Users//anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-as'
ASFLAGS=''
ASMEXT=''
BASERUBY='/usr/bin/ruby --disable=gems'
BOOTSTRAPRUBY=''
BTESTRUBY=''
BUILTIN_ENCOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS=''
CAPITARGET=''
CC='x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang'
CCDLFLAGS=''
CC_VERSION=''
CC_VERSION_MESSAGE=''
CC_WRAPPER=''
CFLAGS='-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe '
CHDIR=''
COMMON_HEADERS=''
COMMON_LIBS=''
COMMON_MACROS=''
CONFIGURE=''
COUTFLAG=''
CP=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-I/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9'
CPPOUTFILE=''
CROSS_COMPILING=''
CSRCFLAG=''
CXX='x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++'
CXXFLAGS='-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++14 -fmessage-length=0'
DEFS=''
DESTDIR=''
DLDFLAGS=''
DLDLIBS=''
DLDSHARED=''
DLEXT2=''
DLEXT=''
DLLWRAP=''
DLNOBJ=''
DOT=''
DOXYGEN=''
DTRACE=''
DTRACE_EXT=''
DTRACE_OBJ=''
DTRACE_OPT=''
DTRACE_REBUILD=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_DEBUG_ENV=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
ENCOBJS=''
ENCSTATIC=''
EXECUTABLE_EXTS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_PREFIX=''
EXTDLDFLAGS=''
EXTLDFLAGS=''
EXTOBJS=''
EXTOUT=''
EXTSTATIC=''
GCC=''
GIT='git'
GNU_LD=''
GREP=''
HAVE_BASERUBY='yes'
HAVE_GIT='yes'
INSTALLDOC=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTALL_STATIC_LIBRARY=''
LD='/Users//anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ld'
LDFLAGS='-L/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs'
LDSHARED=''
LDSHAREDXX=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPATHENV=''
LIBPATHFLAG=''
LIBRUBY=''
LIBRUBYARG=''
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED=''
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC=''
LIBRUBY_A=''
LIBRUBY_ALIASES=''
LIBRUBY_A_OBJS=''
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS=''
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED=''
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE=''
LIBRUBY_SO=''
LIBRUBY_SONAME=''
LIBS=''
LINK_SO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINLIBS=''
MAJOR='2'
MAKEDIRS=''
MAKEFILES=''
MANTYPE=''
MATHN=''
MINIOBJS=''
MINIRUBY=''
MINOR='6'
MJIT_CC=''
MJIT_CFLAGS=''
MJIT_DEBUGFLAGS=''
MJIT_HEADER_FLAGS=''
MJIT_HEADER_INSTALL_DIR=''
MJIT_LDSHARED=''
MJIT_OPTFLAGS=''
MJIT_SUPPORT=''
MKDIR_P=''
NM='/Users//anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-nm'
NULLCMD=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OUTFLAG=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PLATFORM_DIR=''
POSTLINK=''
PRELOADENV=''
PREP=''
RANLIB='/Users//anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ranlib'
RDOCTARGET=''
RI_BASE_NAME=''
RM=''
RMALL=''
RMDIR=''
RMDIRS=''
RPATHFLAG=''
RUBYW_BASE_NAME='rubyw'
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_API_VERSION='$(MAJOR).$(MINOR)'
RUBY_BASE_NAME='ruby'
RUBY_EXEC_PREFIX=''
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_LIB_VERSION=''
RUBY_LIB_VERSION_STYLE=''
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION='2.6.3'
RUBY_SEARCH_PATH=''
RUBY_SO_NAME=''
RUBY_VERSION_NAME='${RUBY_BASE_NAME}-${ruby_version}'
RUNRUBY=''
RUNRUBY_COMMAND=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SOEXT=''
SOLIBS=''
STATIC=''
STRIP='/Users//anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-strip'
SYMBOL_PREFIX=''
TEENY='3'
TEST_RUNNABLE=''
THREAD_MODEL=''
TRY_LINK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES=''
UNIVERSAL_INTS=''
USE_RUBYGEMS=''
WERRORFLAG=''
WINDRES=''
XCC_WRAPPER=''
XCFLAGS=''
XLDFLAGS=''
XRUBY=''
XRUBY_LIBDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR=''
X_FIBER_COROUTINE_H=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_NM=''
ac_ct_OBJCOPY=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
ac_ct_RANLIB=''
arch=''
archincludedir=''
archlibdir=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin18.6.0'
build_vendor='apple'
cflags=''
codesign=''
configure_args=''
cppflags=''
cxxflags=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
debugflags=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dsymutil=''
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin18.6.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libdirname=''
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
optflags=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3'
program_transform_name='s&^&&'
psdir='${docdir}'
ridir=''
ruby_pc=''
ruby_version=''
rubyarchdir=''
rubyarchhdrdir=''
rubyarchprefix=''
rubyhdrdir=''
rubylibdir=''
rubylibprefix=''
rubysitearchprefix=''
rubyw_install_name=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
setup=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sitearch=''
sitearchdir=''
sitearchhdrdir=''
sitearchincludedir=''
sitearchlibdir=''
sitedir=''
sitehdrdir=''
sitelibdir=''
strict_warnflags=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-apple-darwin18'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='darwin18'
target_vendor='apple'
try_header=''
vendorarchdir=''
vendorarchhdrdir=''
vendordir=''
vendorhdrdir=''
vendorlibdir=''
warnflags=''

### -----------

### confdefs.h.

### -----------

/* confdefs.h */

## define PACKAGE_NAME ""

## define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""

## define PACKAGE_VERSION ""

## define PACKAGE_STRING ""

## define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""

## define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77

Comment: I succeeded in installing Ruby. Just for other people following the Learn How to be dangerous enough in Ruby on rails. If you have Anaconda (for Python). It interferes with ruby. So I uninstalled Anaconda (youtube.com/watch?v=hm8AXAyEl4o) and then installed Ruby. Afterwards I installed Anaconda again.